# Zend Framework Db Select Join table help

Tags: sql, zend-framework, select, join, zend-db

I have this query:

```
SELECT g.title, g.asin, g.platform_id, r.rank
        FROM games g
        INNER JOIN ranks r ON ( g.id = r.game_id )
        ORDER BY r.rank DESC
        LIMIT 5`
```

Now, this is my JOIN using `Zend_Db_Select` but it gives me array error

```
$query = $this->select();
        $query->from(array('g' => 'games'), array());
        $query->join(array('r' => 'ranks'), 'g.id = r.game_id', array('g.title', 'g.asin', 'g.platform_id', 'r.rank'));
        $query->order('r.rank DESC');
        $query->limit($top);
        $resultRows = $this->fetchAll($query);
        return $resultRows;
```

Anyone know what I could be doing wrong? I want to get all the columns in 'games' to show and the 'rank' column in the ranks table.

Comment: What's the actual error text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am going to assume you've solved this, but it would be nice to leave the answer for others.

Add this below the instantiation of the select object.

```
$query->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

Comment: Here is the rationale. http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Db-Table-Select-Select-query-cannot-join-with-another-table-tp668445p668447.html

Answer (score 5):

You could also type fewer characters....

```
$query = $this->select()
              ->from(array('g' => 'games'), array('title', 'asin', 'platform_id'))
              ->join(array('r' => 'ranks'), 'g.id = r.game_id', array('rank'))
              ->order('r.rank DESC')
              ->limit($top);
return $this->fetchAll($query);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this. This was a great help in solving problem with same column names in joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd write it:

```
$query = $this->select();
$query->from(array('g' => 'games'), array('title', 'asin', 'platform_id'));
$query->join(array('r' => 'ranks'), 'g.id = r.game_id', array('rank'));
$query->order('r.rank DESC');
$query->limit($top);
$resultRows = $this->fetchAll($query);
return $resultRows;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other example:

```
select n.content, n.date, u.mail 
from notes n, users u
where n.id_us=u.id and reminder=current_date

$query = $this->select()
    ->from(array('n'=>'notes'), 
      array('content', 'date'))
    ->join(array('u'=>'users'), 'n.id_us=u.id and n.reminder=current_date',
      array('mail'))
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false);
return $this->fetchAll($query);
```

That's work fine :)